# required field not working on internet explorer 9 with symfony form

Tags: html, symfony, internet-explorer-9

i've created a form with symfony 2, but my browser internet explorer 9 (running under vista)  doesn't support HTML5. so i get this error message:
     an exception occurs: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column     'name' cannot be null.

i've tried this solution:

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}

{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

but it doesn't change anything!

the submit of the form perfectly works on firefox. does anyone have a real detailled solution for IE9?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [novalidate](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute forces ALL browsers to bypass the HTML5 validation. But as already said, client side validation is not enough. When you actually read the error message your browser tells you, note the word `SQLSTATE` in it. SQL runs on the server side in a normal symfony application, so the error happens on the server, not on the client.

You should add assert annotations to you entity members to validate them on the server. This could look like this in the simplest form for an attribute `$name`:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;
```

Then don't forget the import for the asserts:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

Of course, you may also use other ways to define your validation rules, like xml or yml config. Please refer to the [specific section in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Browser based validation is useful for giving the user instant feedback but you always need to re validate everything on the server side.  As you discovered, not all browsers support validation.  Plus, users can easily bypass browser validation and send bogus information back to the server.

Scroll down to the validation section here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

People who want to comment on my answers should use the comment capability.  Or make their own answer.